# Почему в данном предложении стоят запятые?

Tags: орфография

*Он, не отдыхая, побежал на станцию в депо искать Жухрая.*

Answer (score 1):

Автор (или редактор) посчитал, что это обычное деепричастие, которое "обособляется всегда". Собственно, почему нет? Побежал без отдыха, тесная связь со сказуемым? Да нет, не наблюдается, сравните: "Она идёт по жизни смеясь".

Comment: т.е. если не поставить запятые, то это будет считаться ошибкой?

Comment: В школьном диктанте? Я бы посчитал.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что деепричастие здесь довольно слабо связано с образом действия. Главная причина этого - подразумеваемая неодновременность действий, выраженных деепричастием и сказуемым.

Запятые здесь не обязательны, но желательны. По контексту такое деепричастие лучше обособить. Вообще по правилам не обособляются только одиночные деепричастия, имеющие ярко выраженный характер обстоятельства образа действия. Хотя и это правило носит рекомендательный характер и субъективно, в общем-то все - на волю автора, его лучше придерживаться.

Но в разбираемом примере как раз с образом действия и проблема.

Вот достаточно простое изложение этого принципа.

> Одиночное деепричастие не обособляется, если сохраняет значение
>   глагольности, указывая на образ действия. В этом случае оно обычно
>   приближается по значению к наречию или к сочетанию существительного с
>   предлогом, употребленному в обстоятельственном значении, и не
>   обособляется: Поезд шёл не останавливаясь («безостановочно»); Она
>   говорила об этом улыбаясь («говорила с улыбкой»); Он сидел не шевелясь
>   (как сидел? в каком положении?).

[орфорграмка](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5/)

И сравните, что у нас происходит.
***"Побежал не отдыхая в депо"*** - [побежал,] не отдыхая во время бега.
***"Побежал, не отдыхая, в депо"*** - [побежал,] не отдыхая, перед тем как побежать.

Понятно, что Островский имел в виду второй вариант.

*Вообще по вышеприведенной ссылке стоит прочитать весь текст, очень подробно и доходчивое разбирается это правило во всех деталях.*

Comment: К сказанному Вами добавил бы, что, по Розенталю, обособляется одиночное деепричастие, сохраняющее значение глагольности и СТОЯЩЕЕ ПЕРЕД ГЛАГОЛОМ-СКАЗУЕМЫМ

Comment: @виктор1799 А ссылочку не дадите на конкретное издание? Помню что-то было про "перед сказуемым", но не императивно, вроде. Не только "перед"...

Comment: Можно посмотреть http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113 пункт 6. Там ни о какой императивности не сказано.Вообще, об обособлении одиночных деепричастий там много сказано

Comment: @виктор1799 погодите. Зачем мне ссылка, подтверждающая мои сомнения в ваших формулировках?! Я зацепился за ваше указание, большими буквами набранное: "СТОЯЩЕЕ ПЕРЕД ГЛАГОЛОМ-СКАЗУЕМЫМ"/ Можете  вы дать ссылку именно на это положение у Розенталя?!

Comment: Можно в указанной ссылке посмотреть пункт 7. Там говорится о препозиции одиночного деепричастия

Comment: *Можно посмотреть*.. Сразу и посмотрел.  Тезиса "СТОЯЩЕЕ ПЕРЕД ГЛАГОЛОМ-СКАЗУЕМЫМ", как вы понимаете, там не увидел даже близко.  Прэтому ваше исходное замечание считаю ошибочным.  Остальное к делу не относится.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже правильно отмечено, деепричастие не относится здесь *ни к образу действия*, выраженному глаголом, *ни к одновременному действию*: смысл в том, что персонаж **не стал отдыхать** (= даже не отдохнув) **перед** своим "побеганием", - это независимое действие с отрицанием, условно *предшествующее*. Поэтому обособление здесь подчиняется той же логике, что и в утвердительном варианте "**он, отдохнув, побежал**".

Comment: "Этое" — "этакое"?

Comment: Просто "это". Спасибо.